# Sync notes with Mac and iPhone

Tags: data-synchronization, notes.app

I have recently upgraded to Mountain Lion. I like the Notes application but my notes do not sync with iCloud. The Notes checkbox is checked under **System Preferences** as is my Calendar and Contacts.

The Calendar and Contacts are syncing fine but my notes are not.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: In the desktop Notes app, you can select whether to view / add local notes or iCloud notes. Can you confirm iCloud appears in the sidebar and is selected?

Comment: Also in addition to Dans suggestion, get that the notes are not just saving locally on the iPhone. Open the notes app and tap on the accounts button in the top left. You will see On My iPhone (local only, not synced) and your iCloud account. Select each to see where there notes are living.